# Organizing source (C++)

Tags: c++, code-organization, project-organization

For a scientific project, I have a templated analysis tool (module A) that uses a type of statistical test (module B). The analysis tool (module A) is used on two types of problems (modules C and D). Modules C and D define functions for serializing from different file types.

All modules (A, B, C, and D) use common utilities (module E). Each module consists of several files. I'd really like to organize the modules so that each has its own namespace, and so the source files are in different directories (i.e. emphasize the modularity in the organization).

It's trivial to define the namespace in each file. But I was hoping to use some sort of source tree where the file to #include for each module would include all others inside its own namespace.

I'm not really sure of a good way to organize this. Should I simply use one folder per module and #include using relative paths? Should each module have its own git repository, and compile down to a single library file, which lives in a specified UNIX folder (this would require a true installation for the project to run).

Right now I'm using gcc-4.7, make, and emacs.

Do you know of a way to organize these files to bring out the modularity?

Please forgive me and suggest if there is some other StackOverflow affiliate that is more well-suited for this question. My project runs, but it's much more of a mess than it needs to be!

Comment: I would consider programmers.se as a more suitable platform for your question

Comment: Library files don't need to be put in system folders. You can put them anywhere you like, you only have to make sure that the path is included in `LD_LIBRARY_PATH`.

Answer (score 1):

> But I was hoping to use some sort of source tree where the file to #include for each module would include all others inside its own namespace.

This is the wrong approach. Even if A depends on E at the module level, that does not necessarily entail that all components inside A depend on all components inside E, and you should not force that through the includes.

Includes should be explicit (include everything you really need) and precise (don't include anything on which you don't depend).

That being said, I would organize the code in modules where each module has a separate directory. If a module becomes complex enough to require splitting in submodules, then you can add nested directories, but a single two level hierarchy can be enough.

Comment: Thanks, that's a good point (and might make all of my template headers  slow down compilation). Would you simply put them in parallel directories and `#include "../B/file.h"`?

Comment: And one more thing-- what about cases where really all files in the module are necessary for the module?

Comment: @Oliver: I would put them in separate directories. Then either "#include <B/file.h>" or plain "#include <file.h>" and instruct the compiler on where to find the headers. Regarding the 'one more thing': either they are all part of a single component and they are thus in a single header, or they are in different headers and users should include on demand.